# Plotting points in QGIS using postcodes

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, geocoding, postcode

I want to map a list of facilities around the UK by their Postcodes. I have no Eastings or Northings just postcodes. Is this possible via a Plugin or do I need coordinates.

I am using QGIS Version 3.10.0

Answer (score 2):

You will need some coordinates for your postcodes. The easiest place to get them is by downloading [code-point](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/products/code-point-open) from the Ordnance Survey. You can then join the two layers together to make a map.

Comment: Would I download the information as an CSV file or Geopackage?

Comment: which ever you prefer

Answer (score 2):

The process of adding geospatial coordinates (lat/long or northing/easting) to addresses is called **geocoding**. Ian Turton's answer is probably the easiest method in the UK. For any addresses outside the UK, you can use the MMQGIS plugin ([tutorial](https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-geocode-addresses-using-qgis/)). There are other ways, which you can easily find now that you know the right search term.